# Match repeating exact string of previous matched patten

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I want to match parts of the string that is certain characters long (generic case: it will be a random patten) and will be matched again in the coming part of the entire string.

For the given string example:

> GAC **ATCG** GTAACGCATGAATT **GTCA** GGGTACGCACTGACATG **ATCG** GTTACGAAA **GTCA** C

,

> **ATCG** GTAACGCATGAATT **GTCA** GGGTACGCACTGACATG **ATCG**
>
> **GTCA** GGGTACGCACTGACATG **ATCG** GTTACGAAA **GTCA**

will be the end results.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pattern for 4 at least nucleotides:

```
(?=(([ACTG]{4,}).*\2))
```

But you can choose the number you want or a fixed number, example `(?=(([ACTG]{5}).*\2))`

Exemple in Python:

```
import re

print re.findall(r'(?=(([ACTG]{4,}).*\2))', 'GACATCGGTAACGCATGAATTGTCAGGGTACGCACTGACATGATCGGTTACGAAAGTCAC')
```

Result:

```
[('GACATCGGTAACGCATGAATTGTCAGGGTACGCACTGACAT',     'GACAT'),
 ('ACATCGGTAACGCATGAATTGTCAGGGTACGCACTGACAT',      'ACAT'),
 ('ATCGGTAACGCATGAATTGTCAGGGTACGCACTGACATGATCGGT', 'ATCGGT'),
 ('TCGGTAACGCATGAATTGTCAGGGTACGCACTGACATGATCGGT',  'TCGGT'),
 ('CGGTAACGCATGAATTGTCAGGGTACGCACTGACATGATCGGT',   'CGGT'),
 ('GGTAACGCATGAATTGTCAGGGTA',                      'GGTA'),
 ('ACGCATGAATTGTCAGGGTACGCA',                      'ACGCA'),
 ('CGCATGAATTGTCAGGGTACGCA',                       'CGCA'),
 ('CATGAATTGTCAGGGTACGCACTGACATGA',                'CATGA'),
 ('ATGAATTGTCAGGGTACGCACTGACATGA',                 'ATGA'),
 ('GTCAGGGTACGCACTGACATGATCGGTTACGAAAGTCA',        'GTCA'),
 ('TACGCACTGACATGATCGGTTACG',                      'TACG')]`
```